# CONTROL or once messes with last?

Tags: exception, raku

This loop never stops:

```
class CX::Vaya does X::Control {
    has $.message
}

loop {
    once {
        CX::Vaya.new( message => "I messed up!" ).throw;
    }
    last;
    CONTROL {
        default {
            say "Controlled { .^name }: { .message }"
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps writing

```
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
Controlled CX::Last: <last control exception>
...
```

It could be the `once` bit, because CONTROL phaser with last does finish:

```
loop { say "Hey"; last; CONTROL { default: .message.say } }
# OUTPUT: «Hey␤<last control exception>␤»
```

But I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Loop flow control in Perl 6 is implemented using control exceptions. Thus, `last` is actually throwing a `CX::Last` control exception. Since the `CONTROL` block uses `default`, it is therefore catching the `CX::Last` thrown by `last`, meaning that control is never transferred out of the loop.

The fix is to instead specify which control exception to catch, using `when`:

```
loop {
    once {
        CX::Vaya.new( message => "I messed up!" ).throw;
    }
    last;
    CONTROL {
        when CX::Vaya {
            say "Controlled { .^name }: { .message }"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What Jonathan says.

In more detail:

- The default control flow for P6 is that the next statement follows the current one. So `say 42; say 99;` defaults to doing the `say 42` and then doing the `say 99`.
- P6 has an advanced and pervasive exception system that's used for any exception to this default control flow of one-statement-then-the-immediately-following-statement. It's not just for errors.
- Any exception to the default control flow is called an exception. Many are error exceptions. But there's another category, namely control flow exceptions, or *control exceptions* for short. For example, an explicit or implicit `return`/`leave` from a routine/block is a control exception. (In principle. In reality the compiler/optimizer will elide some of this machinery when appropriate.)
- A `last` is a control exception. It throws the control exception `CX::Last`. Its message payload is `"last control exception"`. You are seeing that message.
- A `CONTROL` block is entered if a control exception applies to its containing block. It can either handle the passed exception or not handle it. If it handles it then control resumes with the statement that follows it. If, as in this example, the `CONTROL` block is at the end of a loop, then the next statement would be an implicit `next` (another control exception) and the loop would restart.
- The code `CONTROL { default { say "Controlled { .^name }: { .message }" }` handles *all* control exceptions, including the one thrown by `last`. So it prints its message and then the loop continues. (Infinitely.)
- In the code `loop { say "Hey"; last; CONTROL { default: .message.say } } # OUTPUT: «Hey␤<last control exception>␤»`, the `CONTROL` block does *display* the exception's message but it doesn't *handle* it. (`default:` is just a label, no different to, say, `I'm-a-label:`, and unrelated to `default { ... }`.) So the `last` control exception isn't handled by your code and instead is handled by the default language handling which is to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

It is really the combination of `CONTROL` and `CX::Succeed` that are preventing the default behaviour of `last`.

---

All of the flow control functions are implemented in terms of exceptions.

Rather than lump them in with regular exceptions in `CATCH`, there is a special handler just for them named `CONTROL`.

Both `CATCH` and `CONTROL` can be thought of as special forms of `given`.
The two main differences being that the topic is set to the exception, and that something special happens if there was a `CX::Succeed`.

If there is a `CX::Succeed` then that indicates the exception or flow-control was successfully handled, and that no further processing needs to happen.

---

There are two ways to get `CX::Succeed` to happen inside of `CONTROL`.

1. `default` block
2. `when` block

(Technically I think that just plain `succeed` should also work, but it doesn't seem to.)

If you are in one of those blocks, and you want the processing to actually continue, you can use `proceed` (`CX::Proceed`).

```perl6
loop {
    once {
        CX::Vaya.new( message => "I messed up!" ).throw;
    }
    last;

    CONTROL {
        default {
            .^name.say;
            proceed if CX::Last;
        }
    }
}
```

It is much better to just use a `when` block that captures exactly what you want to handle specially.
(Note that a postfix `when` does not throw `CX::Succeed`, so normal processing would continue in that case.)

---

`default` is a block prefix. Meaning it always must be followed by a block.

Adding just `:` to the end of an identifier is only used to create a label, and on method calls to remove the parentheses.

So `default:` does absolutely nothing here.

Also `once` is **not** a block prefix. It is a statement prefix. (It just so happens that a block can be treated as a statement.)
There is no reason to add a block there unless you are going to write more than one statement inside of it.

---

```perl6
loop {
    once CX::Vaya.new( message => "I messed up!" ).throw;
    last;

    CONTROL {
        when CX::Vaya {
            .^name.say;
        }
    }
}
```